# How to make JobDetailBean run non concurrently?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am running some scheduled jobs using the Quartz Scheduler. All the jobs in my application are **JobDetailBean** jobs.

I know that using MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean, we can make a job non-concurrent like this:

```
<property name="concurrent"><value>false</value></property>
```

I wonder how we can make the JobDetailBean jobs non-concurrent. **JobDetailBean** jobs run concurrently by default.

The requirement is: jobA needs to run every 5 min but only if the previous instance of it has completed.

Thanks,

Shikha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your job class needs to implement [`StatefulJob`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/1.8.5/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html), or alternatively, if you are using Quartz 2.x, be annotated with [`@DisallowConcurrentExecution`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html).

This is how concurrent execution can be controlled in Quartz, and in particular `MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` just uses different job classes depending on the value of `concurrent`.